# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 when attempting to compile with gfortran

Tags: architecture, duplicates, x86-64, ld, gfortran

something has changed I presume in my environment such that the command I had been using to compile .f90, using gfortran, no longer works.

I use this command

gfortran -o spectrum -I/usr/local/include spectrum.f90 -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 spectrum.f90

where spectrum is my .f90 script.

But using it at the command line now gives me this message:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /var/folders/j6/x389pn_11pvf4zbwyn3dz6rc4vmd16/T//ccoqQofo.o
    /var/folders/j6/x389pn_11pvf4zbwyn3dz6rc4vmd16/T//ccFaSoMl.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where previously a working executable appeared.

What changed? I made some changes to the .f90, which I subsequently reversed. But I don't understand how the error can have arisen due to a change in the program - apart from anything else, when I attempt to use an older, backup version of the same program that was unmodified, I get the same error!

What's more, I am referred to different files containing this 'duplicate', when I delete the two pasted above.

But I cannot even access these files / locations:

```
/var/tmp//cc78ilM3.o
/var/tmp//ccPP60rG.o
```

A colleague mentioned using a utility such as omnidisk to clean up spurious files like this?
But, what has even caused these files to appear and result in this conflict as per the ld?

Comment: Why do you have `spectrum.f90` listed twice on the command line? (i'm not a gfortran user but that looks unusual. Might suggest you are compiling your `.f90` file twice into the executable causing `main` to appear more than onceand thus the error `duplicate symbol _main in:`

Comment: What happens if you use this command `gfortran -o spectrum -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3 spectrum.f90` (I've simply removed one of the spectrum.f90 that appears)

Comment: OK...OK...this will probably win a record as the dumbest thing ever posted as a programming problem...my sincere apologies. The problem was just what you highlight.

Comment: I just didn't look closely enough

Comment: Not a stupid question at all.